# CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION problem with simple quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping, xsd

I'm trying to do the following in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [dbo].[XYZSchema] AS 
N'schema content'
GO
```

The problem is that `schema content` contains a quote (') in a regexp and is breaking the instruction:

```
 N' ..... <xsd:pattern value="\w+([-+.'] ..... '
```

Is there a way to escape the quote and maintain the correctnes of the regexp, or declare the Expresion of CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing a varchar (well, nvarchar) literal. The way to escape single quotes within such a literal is to double them up:

```
N' ..... <xsd:pattern value="\w+([-+.''] ..... '
```

From [Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx):

> If a character string enclosed in single quotation marks contains an embedded quotation mark, represent the embedded single quotation mark with two single quotation marks.